# What is the proper way to normalise default imports between TS and Babel?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

TypeScript compiler and Babel handle default exports a bit differently.
For instance:

```
import Button from 'grommet/components/Button'
console.log(Button)
```

This shall log `undefined` if compiled through `tsc`, yet it works as intended with Babel. However, if we do this:

```
import * as Button from 'grommet/components/Button'
console.log(Button)
```

This says `Button { ... }` in TS and `{ default: Button { ... } }` in Babel.

This discrepancy could be fixed by raising a flag `esModuleInterop` in the compiler options.

*As an aside, the other ways to do without `esModuleInterop` is to compile first with `tsc` and then with Babel, but it is slow, and we lose hot-swap capabilities. We also could fix it in the runtime like `Imported = _Imported.default || _Imported`, but this is error-prone and burdens maintenance.*

The question is, is `esModuleInterop` the right solution for this? If so, is there any use case for `"esModuleInterop": false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is, is esModuleInterop the right solution for this

Yes. That is exactly what it is designed for.

> If so, is there any use case for "esModuleInterop": false?

`esModuleInterop: true` generates *more* JavaScript to make the magic work *just like babel does*. If you want a slight performance bump of not doing *magic mapping* of default exports (like babel) don't use the flag.